Jmeter property
I have a property file like this
baseurl=xxx
secondUrl=${baseurl}\path1
thirdUrl=${baseur}\path2

if I pass baseurl value in the command line using -q, I can get the value of baseurl correctly but I am not getting the value of the secondUrl which should be baserul+\\path1. Any suggestion on how to pass the value of baseurl in secondurl and thirdurl
I can anyways append baseurl value on Jmeter UI itself but if there is a way to pass baserul so that secondurl and thirdurl also have it would be good


Amend your .properties file to use __P() function and escape \ character like:
baseurl=xxx
secondUrl=${__P(baseurl,)}\\path1
thirdUrl=${__P(baseurl,)}\\path2


Use __eval() and __P() functions combination to read the values in your script like:

${__eval(${__P(baseurl,)})}
${__eval(${__P(secondUrl,)})}
${__eval(${__P(thirdUrl,)})}



More information on JMeter Functions concept: Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction

I made these changes, but still not getting the correct value. I tried to get secondUrl value with props.getProperty("secondUrl") in JSR sample, it prints value as it is ${__eval(${__P(baseurl,)})}\YYYYYY. And when I tried to print with ${__P(secondUrl)}, it gives error as Script2.groovy: 3: unexpected char: '' @ line 3, column 79.
1"+${__eval(${__P(baseurl,)})}\YYYYYY);

I'm not telepathic enough to guess where and how you're using the property. If you're smart enough to do Groovy programming you should be smart enough to pass the ${__eval(${__P(secondUrl,)})} into Parameters section and use the value in the script. If you're not smart enough use the following code new  org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable(props.get('secondUrl')).execute() and get familiarized with Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For? article
